# Why does the line number of the source code not match when debugging on the device

Tags: android, debugging

Why the line number of the source code does not match when debugging on the device. The version API23 of the source code corresponds to the version of the android 6.0.1 installed on the phone.
My application writes to own error-log information about exceptions and the call stack. I see an entry in the log that the function in line 466 has raised an exception. I run the debugger and I see that this function is in another line. What it means and whether it is possible to correct the situation?

```
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:466)  Wrong line number!!!! In source code is line 460
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:44)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:**.***********.************.DataEngine$Photo.getPhotoBody(DataEngine.java:982)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:**.***********.************.services.IntentServicePhotoByReportUpload.Job(IntentServicePhotoByReportUpload.java:149)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:**.***********.************.services.IntentServicePhotoByReportUpload.onHandleIntent(IntentServicePhotoByReportUpload.java:84)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
Stack call[ver:1.2.116]:android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the source code you have does not match with the code running on the device. This can be because of manufacturer changes, hot-fixes and so on.

I don't think there's any good way around it unless you can get your hands on the exact version of the source that the device is running.

Comment: Yeah, these line numbers are in OS parts of the code. Unless you have the source code of the android framework of the particular phone you're running on, you're not going to get matching line numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I assumed this, but I hoped that there is a small chance that this is something else and can be corrected.

Comment: not quite related but if you are using any tool/plugin that doing something on top of compiled code(like RetroLambda) then you can face such issue.